# Generating an infinite number of objects in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, timer, uiimage

I'm working on a game right now, in which every second, I want to create x number of new UIImage objects that begin at the top of the screen. After they have been instantiated, I want them automatically to fall down until they reach the bottom of the screen, at which point I no longer have any use for them.

Its almost like raindrops - X number of them are created every second, and they each fall down at different speeds.

I'm getting really confused as to how I would even just design my program to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: found a terrific resource to handle this exact scenario. It does require you to use cocos2d, but it explains it in a very clear and understandable manner.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Are they all copies of the same image, or at least copies of one among a limited set of images?
For such a game-like, graphics intensive app I would seriously consider using OpenGL ES, although the learning curve is steep for people familiar with UIKit only. Fortunately, there are third party, open-source libraries such as Cocos2d that make efficient 2d graphics almost as easy to code as UIKit.

Regarding your question in particular, I haven't watched the video mentioned by @ctrahey, but I can think of these patterns:

1. Have a (finite) 'pool' of reusable objects, which size is equal to the maximum amount of instances that might appear on screen at any given time. You definitely *want* to set this limit, since graphics performance is not infinite. Each time an object falls off-screen, 'reset' its state and reuse it (from the top, again). UITableView does something like this with table cells.
2. Create the instances on demand, and destroy them (release->dealloc) once they go off-screen.

You have to balance the runtime cost of creating/destroying instances vs. the cost/inconvenience of resetting objects.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. What I'm thinking of doing right now is to put every new UIImage object into an NSMutableArray and then somehow delete the ones that have gone off screen. That way perhaps I could also update each element in the NSMutableArray at the same time.

Comment: You definitely want all your 'map objects' (too use game terminology) in one array, to easily manage them. `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:` comes in handy.

Comment: You might want to check the 'height' of each particle -say- each frame, and delete/reuse the ones that reached the bottom. I strongly recommend reuse instead of lots of `alloc/init` and `dealloc`s each frame. But `UIImage` caches texture (image) data when creating a new instance with a recently used image, so it shouldn't be such an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Run a piece of code every second

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(dispatchSomeRaindrops) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Step 2: Create some particles, send them down the screen, and clean them up when they reach the bottom.

```
- (void)dispatchSomeRaindrops
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"safari.png"]];

        CGFloat halfHeight = view.frame.size.height / 2;
        CGFloat x = arc4random() % (int)self.view.frame.size.width;
        view.center = CGPointMake(x, -halfHeight);

        [self.view addSubview:view];

        NSTimeInterval duration = 10 + arc4random() % 10;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            float endY = self.view.frame.size.height + halfHeight;
            view.center = CGPointMake(x, endY);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the Core Animation video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=421) from WWDC 2011, and near the end there is a bit on "Replicators", and it sounds like exactly what you are after.